# How to combine two command outputs line by line?

Tags: command-line, text-formatting

let's say I have these two commands:

```
$ cat file1
file1_a
file1_b
file1_c
file1_d
```

And:

```
$ cat file2
file2_a
file2_b
file2_c
file2_d
```

How can I combine these outputs using a custom separator (e.g. `...`) so that I get the following output:

```
$ # some fancy command like { cat file1 & cat file2 } | combine --separator='...'
file1_a...file2_a
file1_b...file2_b
file1_c...file2_c
file1_d...file2_d
```

?

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The custom separator is more than one character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use the `paste` command.

```
paste -d. file1 - - file2 < /dev/null
```

produces desired output

```
file1_a...file2_a
file1_b...file2_b
file1_c...file2_c
file1_d...file2_d
```

`-` refers to stdin, we use this twice to triple our dots `</dev/null` is used because we do not want anything between those dots.

Comment: Cool, but can I just have two arbitrary commands combined (not just files, but stdout piped output) and pass their output to paste somehow?

Comment: `paste -d. <(command1) - - <(command2) < /dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

If you `paste` two files they will be delimited by a tabulator. So just replace the tabulator with your desired separator:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | sed -e 's/\t/.../'
```

If your content has a tabulator then invent a new separator which does not occur like %:

```
$ paste -d% file1 file2 | sed -e s/%/.../
```

Answer (score 0):

This is @zacharybrady's answer, but to be more like what you asked for. It terms of input processes. That I guess you will extend.

`paste -d. <(cat file1) - - <(cat file2) < /dev/null`

Thanks to @zacharybrady for the bit I was stuck on. I had got to this `join <(cat -n file1) <(cat -n file2) | cut -d" " -f2-`, as I had forgotten about `paste`. I could not get the field separator correct though.

Note: I have discovered that `paste` is not utf-8 compliant. It only processes the first byte after the `-d`, so `-d…` is broken. (I am using debian jessie, paste (GNU coreutils) 8.23)